# Integrating datatables.js with asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, filter

I am trying to implement [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) on my asp.net gridview. I have included the necessary js and css files.

I am applying the datatables using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myGridview').dataTable();
});
```

but it is not working. It is showing the **exception in console** :

> "Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined"

can anyone help me out with this ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of jQuery are you including?

Comment: //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js as suggested on the datatables site

Comment: Then it sounds like your table doesn't have a `thead` or `tbody` tag

Comment: yes i read that while googling this issue. but asp.net gridview is creating the table structure itself. So how can i deal with that. Please share your views if you have implemented it on gridview.

Comment: datatables requires the table to have a thead and tbody section -- I'm not familiar with C# or asp.net though, so I'm not sure how to make that happen

Comment: hi thanks for your interest. I have solved the issue and posted my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Nice man! I'm glad you got it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the work around to this problem.

This error shows up because datatables.js requires thead and tbody attributes. Now asp.net gridview does not generate the  attribute itself when it is rendered as html which caused datatables.js to fail.

So in order to generate  in gridview please add following code in page load which will create the   attributes for gridview.

```
 GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;

//adds <thead> and <tbody> elements

GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection =  TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

and you are good to go with datatables.js